# Group rows in one file based on column value

Tags: shell-script

I have "csv" spreadsheet as below

```
abc,12345,qwerty,A
xyz,12380,qwetty,R
abc,12389,qwerty,A
xyz,12324,qwetty,R
```

I would like to combine rows with similar values in columns 1, 2 and 4. Also, i would like to replace the last two alphabets of column 3 by "**". Sample of the output is as below:

```
abc,123**,qwerty,A
abc,123**,qwerty,A
xyz,123**,qwetty,R
xyz,123**,qwetty,R
```

Total number of lines is more than one Million!

Comment: Hi @Arpit. You want to ` combine rows with similar values in columns 1, 2 and 4` or organize the rows` **OR**  'combine rows with similar values in columns 1 or  2 or 4`? thanks for any additional clarifications!

Comment: @Goro, i want to organize rows with similar value. Its re arranging rows with similar values.Thanks for correction.

Comment: There is a difference between organizing the rows by one similar value or multiple similar values?

Comment: Yes. My requirement to organize based on multiple similar values. To be more specific, all rows with exactly same value in column 1,3 and 4 should be condition, based on which rows are arranged together. And then just replace last 2 digit of row 2 by *

Comment: You can simply run the command `sort` on the file that you would like to organize, just sort file  ;-)

Comment: Yes. But i think that can be done based on 1 column value, not 3 at same time. In example i shown same column value. But in actual file, all 3 are variables.

Comment: Did you consider giving multiple keys to `sort`? And, you want column 3 to be modified in your spec, but show col2 with the stars?

Comment: I'd encourage the use of the phrase `rows with the *same* values in columns 1, 2, and 4` -- as "similar" could imply variation; unless you're OK with variation?

Answer (score 2):

To sort your file first by col1 then by col2 then by col4:

```
$ sort -t, -k1,1 -k2,2 -k4,4 file
abc,12345,qwerty,A                                                                                        
abc,12389,qwerty,A
xyz,12324,qwetty,R
xyz,12380,qwetty,R
```

Then to obfuscate the 2nd field, you could do

```
$ sort -t, -k1,1 -k2,2 -k4,4 file | sed 's/..,/**,/2'
abc,123**,qwerty,A                                                                                        
abc,123**,qwerty,A
xyz,123**,qwetty,R
xyz,123**,qwetty,R
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sort file | awk -F',' '{ sub(/..$/,"**",$2) }1' OFS=','
abc,123**,qwerty,A
abc,123**,qwerty,A
xyz,123**,qwetty,R
xyz,123**,qwetty,R
```

In case you would like to change the comma separator to tab. you can use this command:

```
sort file | sed 's/,/\t/g' | awk -F'\t' '{ sub(/..$/,"**",$2) }1' OFS='\t'
abc 123**   qwerty  A
abc 123**   qwerty  A
xyz 123**   qwetty  R
xyz 123**   qwetty  R
```

Comment: why are you changing the separator to tab? The question seems pretty clear about commas.

Comment: @glenn jackman. Correct! It seems I missed the first part when wrote the answer quickly. Thank you for catching that! ;-)